# Reference request: multivariable (homogeneous) polynomial division algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

**Reference request: multivariable (homogeneous) polynomial division algorithm**

I am looking for a reference for a result that shows that a (homogeneous) polynomial in an even number of variables (or any number of variables) can be divided by linear polynomials corresponding to roots.

**Context:**
The specific application I have in mind is rigorously proving the following facts related to resultants:

> **1.** Show that $\det (Syl (f,g)) = \lambda\ \Pi_{i=1,j=1}^{i=n,j=m} (r_i - s_j)$, where $Syl(f,g)$ is the Sylvester matrix of the degree $n$ polynomial $f$ and the degree $m$ polynomial $g$.
>
> **2.** Given: $\det (Syl (f,g)) = \lambda\ \Pi_{i=1,j=1}^{i=n,j=m} (r_i - s_j)$, show that $\lambda = 1$.

Basically I want to show that since the points $(r_i : s_j)$ are obviously zeros of the determinant of the Sylvester matrix, the corresponding linear polynomials divide $\det(Syl(f,g))$ (for the first part). This could be done I think if I could cite the existence of a suitable multivariable polynomial division algorithm. For the second part, I'll figure it out, but now I have no idea besides Vieta's formulas.

**Related questions whose answers don't answer my question (I think):**
[Algorithms for factoring multivariate polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703962/algorithms-for-factoring-multivariate-polynomials)
[Division algorithm of multivariate polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874170/division-algorithm-of-multivariate-polynomial)
[Division algorithm for multivariate polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316752/division-algorithm-for-multivariate-polynomials)
[How to show that a root of a bivariate homogeneous polynomial divides the polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905896/how-to-show-that-a-root-of-a-bivariate-homogeneous-polynomial-divides-the-polyno)

Comment: A polynomial in $n$-variables over a field is also a polynomial in one variable over the field of rational functions of $n-1$ variables.

Comment: @Hurkyl I didn't know that -- thank you for the insight! This is probably what they were going for, since the next section is about the field of rational functions associated to a curve.